# Load testing of a classic ASP application in VS 2010 Ultimate

Tags: visual-studio-2010, asp-classic, load-testing

I wish to perform performance testing(load testing) of a legacy(classic) ASP web application, which runs on IIS using VS 2010 Ultimate.

Can you please post the steps.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There is absolutely no difference testing a classic ASP app from any other with VS 2010 Ultimate.

Trawl the Microsoft text on the subject [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd293540.aspx).

The basic process is to create/record some web tests to hit pages on your site.
Then use the load test to combine these for running against your target site.